# When I get error when try to set text for Label?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following for label:

```
self.countLabel .text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", --self.total];
```

Where `self.total` is  `NSSInteger` property

Comment: Please read about [how to ask good questions](//stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and try to edit your question. With high quality questions you will receive better answers faster. Thanks!

Comment: Please specify your error. and try removing the space between the `countLabel` and `text`

Comment: you need to give %d for an integer and %@ for a string

Comment: @Mr.T More correctly, you use `%@` for an object type, not just string (`NSString`). `NSInteger` isn't a class, it's a primitive type. And you don't use `%d` with `NSInteger` since `NSInteger` isn't an `int`.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me @rmaddy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try doing:

```
self.countLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", (long)--self.total];
```